# UIButton buttonWithType:101, Will they reject my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store, itunes, ios

Greetings,

In one of my projects I wanted to create back type button(with pointer) in the navigation bar, I googled around and found that using the following code, it can be achieved.

> UIButton *someButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:101];
>   UIBarButtonItem *someBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];

I want to upload this app on Apple's app store.
Is there any chance that this will get my app rejected, since buttonWithType:101 is not documented any where?
Also i m not using this bar button item in its generic way, i.e. it wont pop the view controller.
Please guide.
Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

most probably yes.. in some cases, few things do slip under the radar, but why take chances..

if you are doing this for your client/company, would you risk having a rejection from app store on your hands..

its safer to create a pointed button image and use it with custom button...

Comment: I agree - at the same time I really don't understand why apple don't let people use this button type.

Answer (score 8):

I propose that you generate Image for your need, just by running this code and delete it after you generate the image:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
...
someButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:101];


    UIBarButtonItem *someBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =  someBarButton;
...
}
```

and

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    ....
    UIImage *img1 = [someButton backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal];

    NSData *newData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img1);

    NSFileManager *fileManager =[NSFileManager defaultManager];

    BOOL filecreationSuccess = [fileManager createFileAtPath:@"/Users/macbookmac/Desktop/tester.png" contents:newData attributes:nil]; 

...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to control what text appears in the Navigation controller's back button, you can do that with the UIViewController's UINavigationItem.  It can contain both the title for the current view and the text to use for the next view's "back" button.  This can be set in XIB as well.